# Init Many NSArrays inside For Loop

Tags: nsarray

I would like to do the following but Xcode can't make sense of duck[x]:

```
NSArray *duck1;
NSArray *duck2;
NSArray *duck3;

for ( int x=0; x < count; x++ ) {
    duck[x]= @[[otherArrayOne objectAtIndex:x], [otherArrayTwo objectAtIndex:x], [otherArrayThree objectAtIndex:x], ];

}

but xCode doesn't like:  'duck[x]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is right in prompting compile time error. Variable 'duck' is un-declared in your code.

You just have to declare `'duck'` variable and initialize it. Add following lines after `NSArray *duck3;` variable declarations.

```
NSArray *duck = @[duck1,duck2,duck3];
int count = [duck count];
```